# Creating custom post type and taxonomy archives and pretty URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom post type, `Local Pages` and two different taxonomies: `Locations` and `Services`.

As of now, the custom post type works. However the urls are not pretty. They look something like: `http://domain.com/?localpage=%post_name%`

Ideally, I'd like to create an archive for the post type and the taxonomies.

For example, the main archive would be something like `http://domain.com/localpage`, which would list all of the posts in that post type. I assume this would require it's own archive template.

I'd also like to create a category list page for my taxonomies, where the URL would be something like `http://domain.com/localpage/locations` and `http://domain.com/localpage/services`. Both of these pages would essentially list the all of categories or items of the particular taxonomy. Filter the links on each of those pages to the next taxonomy.

An example of how this would work would be:

> **Locations:** Abbott, CA; Aberdeen, CA; Cable, CA; Strawberry, CA; Zuver,
>   CA
>
> **Services:** Aluminum Adjustable Patio Covers; Insulated Patio Covers;
>   Store Front Awnings; Sunroom Enclosures.
>
> When visiting `http://domain.com/localpage/locations`, you would see
>   the above listed locations. Upon clicking on any particular location,
>   you would then be sent to something like
>   `http://domain.com/localpage/%location_name%/services` where it would
>   list all the services for that location. Upon clicking on a service,
>   you would be taken to the post at something like
>   `http://domain.com/localpage/%location_name%/%service_name%/%post_name%`

How might I accomplish this and what page template files (archive.php, single.php, etc) are needed?

Here's the code I'm using in my 'functions.php' to create the custom post type and taxonomies.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Local Page Custom Post Type
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
function create_local_pages() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Local Pages', 'post type general name' ), // Tip: _x('') is used for localization
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Local Page', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'Local Page' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Local Page' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Local Page' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Local Page' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Local Page' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Local Pages' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Local Pages found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Local Pages found in Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $annoucement_args = array(
        'labels' =>$labels,
        'singular_label' => __('Local Page'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'has_archive' => true,
     );
    register_post_type('localpage', $annoucement_args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_local_pages');



/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Local Page Taxonomies
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_action( 'init', 'build_locations', 0 );
    function build_locations() {
        register_taxonomy( 'location', 'localpage', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Locations', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    }

add_action( 'init', 'build_services', 0 );
    function build_services() {
        register_taxonomy( 'services', 'localpage', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Services', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    }

add_action( 'init', 'build_keywords', 0 );
    function build_keywords() {
        register_taxonomy( 'keyword', 'localpage', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Keywords', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional information**

In the example provided, the local pages are pages within the site that relate to a geographic location and a single, particular service. Hence my reference to them as "local pages" for the custom post type. They could be named anything different for that sake.

From my understanding, this is an SEO play on his behalf. Most of the content is identical with the exception of some keyword and location changes throughout the content. Not something I'm real fond of, but I'm attempting to deliver what the client asked for.

Comment: This is something that I'm converting from a static .html site into WordPress. You can see how the .html site is currently working and what I'm trying to replicate here: http://www.patiodepot-inc.com/AreasWeService/State-NORTHERN_CALIFORNIA/

Comment: it's a bit difficult to see exactly what you're trying to replicate- all of the pages that aren't just lists of links seem identical in their content, and the detailed services links all 404. what is a *local page* exactly? how do you associate a service to a location if locations are just another taxonomy, and not actual post objects?

Comment: Do you have update the permalink settings, that the nice url works also on your custom post type?

Comment: @Milo My client asked me to take that html site (which has tons of broken links) and put it into WordPress and make it work. Page creation/editing is much simpler in WordPress, than editing each of those pages in Dreamweaver or whatever is used.

If there's a better way of associating locations to a post besides a taxonomy, I'm all ears. It's the only thing I could think of that would allow the post to be assigned multiple services and locations. And this is where it got convoluted for me in creating the directories/archives of the taxonomies.

Comment: @bueltge I have my permalink structure set for wordpress, however the permalink structure for the custom post types is http://domain.com/?localpage=%post_name%

Comment: You have the `rewrite` post type argument set to `false`. Removing this line should give you pretty permalinks.

Comment: I don't think that using custom taxonomies is the best idea here. Why not use custom meta boxes instead? See http://www.wpexplorer.com/creating-highly-customized-post-types-with-custom-meta-boxes

Comment: @Chip: set the rewrite param to true or custom value, see [dokumentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: @bungeshea How could I link the two custom meta boxes together? For instance, a post has multiple locations selected in one of the custom meta boxes and multiple services selected in another metabox. How could I create a directory of all the locations and then if you were to click on a location it take you to a directory of services of that location. If you were then to click that service it would take you to the associated post. And vice versa with directory linking.

Comment: @bungeshea The `rewrite` argument fixed the permalink issue. Is there a way can offer partial bounty to your answer?

Comment: So rethinking this whole process and my end product, I'm curious if I'm going about this the wrong way with using custom post types. My end product is going to be a page that has some stock content and images and dynamic content (locations, services and keywords -- currently used as post titles) and images. The main thing that I need to focus on is creating a directory of the dynamic content and linking them to-and-fro and getting to the end product. I think I'm confusing myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve permalinks like `http://example.com/localpage/%post_name%/`, you will need to set the [`rewrite` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) when registering the custom post type:

```
$annoucement_args = array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
    ...
);
```

I don't think that using custom taxonomies is the best idea here. Why not use custom meta boxes instead? See this [WP Explorer article](http://www.wpexplorer.com/creating-highly-customized-post-types-with-custom-meta-boxes) for guidance.

Comment: If I were to use custom fields and create a multiple selection checkbox field, could I then create a page that lists all of those terms with something similar to `get_term_by`?